# ANTLR rewrite query text to repeat text with earlier nodes

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

I am new to ANTLR and am trying to parse queries using the following

```
grammar SearchEngineQuery; 

options { language = CSharp2; output = AST; } 

tokens {
AndNode;
}

LPARENTHESIS : '('; 
RPARENTHESIS : ')'; 

AND    : 'and'; 
OR     : 'or'; 
ANDNOT : 'andnot'; 
NOT    : 'not'; 
NEAR    : 'near'; 


fragment CHARACTER : ('a'..'z'|'0'..'9'|'-'); 
fragment QUOTE     : ('"'); 
fragment WILDCARD  : ('*'|'?'); 
fragment SPACE     : (' '|'\n'|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C'); 

WILD_STRING 
   : (CHARACTER)* 
     ( 
       ('?') 
       (CHARACTER)* 
     )+ 
   ; 
PREFIX_STRING 
   : (CHARACTER)+
     ( 
       ('*')  
     )+ 
   ; 
WS     : (SPACE) { $channel=HIDDEN; }; 
PHRASE : (QUOTE)(WORD)(WILDCARD)?((SPACE)+(WORD)(WILDCARD)?)*(QUOTE); 
WORD   : (CHARACTER)+; 

startExpression  : nearExpression; 
nearExpression     : andExpression (NEAR^ andExpression)*; 
andExpression 
  :  (andnotExpression        ->  andnotExpression) 
     (AND? a=andnotExpression -> ^(AndNode $andnotExpression $a))*  
  ; 

andnotExpression : orExpression (ANDNOT^ orExpression)*; 
orExpression     : notExpression (OR^ notExpression)* ; 
notExpression    : (NOT^)? (phraseExpression | wildExpression | prefixExpression | atomicExpression); 
phraseExpression : (PHRASE^);
wildExpression    : (WILD_STRING^); 
prefixExpression    : (PREFIX_STRING^); 
atomicExpression :  WORD | LPARENTHESIS! andExpression RPARENTHESIS!;
```

This seems to work ok for general queries. However, the case of `a near (b or c)` needs to be actually handled as:

[image]

and `a near (b or c and (d or e))` needs to be handled as:

[image]

I am unable to determine how to do this. Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What about `a and (b or c)`? Should that also be transformed into `(a and b) or (a and c)`? And `a near (b or c and (d or e))`?

Comment: The a and (b or c) can be handled as it is. It is the near option that needs to be processed by breaking up the query. As for a near (b or c and (d or e)) should be ideally be broken up too.
Sorry for the delay in responding. I am new to stackexchange and just kept looking at the answers value on this question in my profile. Now I know better.

Comment: One more thing, your grammar allows for `a near x near (b or c)`, is that correct? If so, what AST should that produce?

Comment: @Bart, a near x near (b or c) should be parsed as (a near (x near (b or c))) => (a near x near c) or (a near x near c). I know it can get pretty complex. I guess I will need to check on the complexity of the query and then decide if I can allow that query to be processed or stop execution of code and ask for a revised query to be input

Comment: @Puneet, hmmm, I see. There's quite a bit of AST re-ordering going on. I don't think this can be done in the grammar itself (either in the combined grammar or from a tree grammar), but I could be wrong of course... I'll think about it a bit more, but as of now, I'd say you'll have to manually reorder the AST yourself after creating it (see the API for CommonTree to see how to get a hold of the children, and other attributes of said class). Good luck.

Comment: @Bart - Thanks for the pointer. I'll take a look at the CommonTree API.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be able to achieve this by using a multiple pass tree rewriting grammar.
The rules should be fairly short.

something similar as this for the OR case:

```
orCaseRight: a=. NEAR ^(OR x=. y=.) -> ^(OR ^(NEAR $a $x) ^(NEAR $a $y));
orCaseLeft: ^(OR x=. y=.) NEAR a=. -> ^(OR ^(NEAR $a $x) ^(NEAR $a $y));
```

in topDown add an action that sets a `rewrite` flag, whenever a rule matched, so you can apply this grammar as long as the `rewrite` flag is set.

I use this to optimize/precalculate math expressions and it works like a charm.

Comment: Sorry, but how would I loop the grammar ? Can you explain this further ?

Comment: This you would do in your parser calling code. In mine it looks something like this:        `// simplify expressions
        while (true) {
          CommonTreeNodeStream nodes = new CommonTreeNodeStream(downup);
          ExpressionSimplifying expressionSimplifying =
              new ExpressionSimplifying(nodes);
          downup = (Tree) expressionSimplifying.downup(downup, false);
          if (!expressionSimplifying.did_rewrite)
            break;
        }`

Comment: Sorry for the code mess, return is not well supported in comments. Basically what I do is call the `TreeRewriter` with the result of the previous pass as long as the rewriter still rewrites something.